# How to use Android's C2DM in an extremely simple way

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

Is there any tutorial or documentaiton on C2DM which is incredibly simple as just sending a request from a server and then I use that request and manipulate it in Android? All of the documentation Android provides and the 2 examples (Chrome to Phone and Jumpnote)

I am coding in Java, by the way, and I just got accepted to the C2DM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with Google I/O 2011 Video: [Android + App Engine: A Developer's Dream Combination](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-app-engine-a-developer-s-dream-combination.html). A [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html). If you also using App Engine, the Google Plugin for Eclipse 2.4.0 (beta) it was extremely simple. You only need to create an App Engine Connected Android project.